# What modules should be included in CMakeList.txt for Approximate Nearest Neighbor Searching?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-modules, approximate-nn-searching

I have compiled [ANN-library](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) and need to use it in a C++ file for segmentation evaluation

I have set the CMakeList.txt, which is using ITK and ANN libraries as follows:

```
PROJECT(EvaluateSegmentationResult)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(ANN_LIB /home/user/tools/ann_1.1.2/lib/)
set(ANN_PATH /home/user/tools/ann_1.1.2/include/)

#FIND_PACKAGE(ITK)
find_package(ITK COMPONENTS
        ITKBinaryMathematicalMorphology
        ITKCommon
        ITKIOImageBase
        ITKImageFunction
        ITKImageGrid
        ITKImageIntensity
        ITKMathematicalMorphology
        ITKThresholding
        ITKImageIO
        )
IF(ITK_FOUND)
    INCLUDE(${ITK_USE_FILE})
ELSE(ITK_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR
    "ITK not found. Please set ITK_DIR.")
ENDIF(ITK_FOUND)

FIND_PATH(ANN_PATH NAMES ANN)
FIND_LIBRARY(ANN_LIB NAMES ann PATHS ${ANN_PATH})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${ANN_PATH})

ADD_EXECUTABLE( EvaluateSegmentationResult EvaluateSegmentationResult.cpp)
#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( EvaluateSegmentationResult ITKIO ITKBasicFilters ITKCommon ${ITK_LIBRARIES} ${ANN_LIB})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( EvaluateSegmentationResult ${ITK_LIBRARIES} ${ANN_LIB})
```

However, it raises an error once I am compiling the C++ file:

```
/home/user/tools/EvaluationSourceCode/EvaluateSegmentationResult.cpp:86: undefined reference to `annAllocPts(int, int)'
/home/user/tools/EvaluationSourceCode/EvaluateSegmentationResult.cpp:95: undefined reference to `ANNkd_tree::ANNkd_tree(double**, int, int, int, ANNsplitRule)'
/home/user/tools/EvaluationSourceCode/EvaluateSegmentationResult.cpp:135: undefined reference to `annAllocPts(int, int)'
/home/user/tools/EvaluationSourceCode/EvaluateSegmentationResult.cpp:144: undefined reference to `ANNkd_tree::ANNkd_tree(double**, int, int, int, ANNsplitRule)'
/home/user/tools/EvaluationSourceCode/EvaluateSegmentationResult.cpp:175: undefined reference to `annDeallocPts(double**&)'
/home/user/tools/EvaluationSourceCode/EvaluateSegmentationResult.cpp:176: undefined reference to `annDeallocPts(double**&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/EvaluateSegmentationResult.dir/build.make:128: recipe for target 'EvaluateSegmentationResult' failed
make[3]: *** [EvaluateSegmentationResult] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/EvaluateSegmentationResult.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/EvaluateSegmentationResult.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/EvaluateSegmentationResult.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/EvaluateSegmentationResult.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'EvaluateSegmentationResult' failed
make: *** [EvaluateSegmentationResult] Error 2
```

It seems the issue is related to link libraries. should I add any specific line or module to the `CMakeList.txt`?

Comment: Perhaps, `ANN_LIB` is not found? What is the value of this variable? Try adding `message("ANN_LIB: ${ANN_LIB}")` at the end of your CMake file. The `FIND_LIBRARY()` call will set this variable for you, so you should not set the same variable at the top of the CMake file...

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are defined in ANN.lib itself, so you haven't missed adding any libraries. The ${ANN_PATH} variable passed as the PATH argument in your find_library call points to the header include folder. You should make it point to the folder that contains the library, and do an if-check to see it is found before proceeding to the target_link_libraries call.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the issue by just adding `-lANN -LlibANN` to the `target_link_libraries()` call:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( EvaluateSegmentationResult ${ITK_LIBRARIES} -lANN -LlibANN)
```